# First Scraper > INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: scrapy

When I 'scrapy shell "URL", I get the response with XPATH, but when I try to run the 'scrapy crawl bot', none.

I've already tryed .extract(), .get() and .getall()

```
import scrapy


class AcicbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'acicbot'
    allowed_domains = ['www.acichapeco.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.acichapeco.com.br/associados/_busca_/?sc3=&c1&pg=0']

    def parse(self, response):
        #Extracting the content using xpath selectors
        nomes = response.xpath('//*[@id="p1344"]/a[2]/label/text()').extract()
        emails = response.xpath('//*[@id="tela"]/div/div[5]/a/text()').extract()
        sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="tela"]/div/div[6]/a/text()').extract()

        #Give the extracted content row wise
        for item in zip(emails,sites):
            #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
            scraped_info = {
                'nome':item[0],
                'email':item[1],
                'site':item[2],
            }

            #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
            yield scraped_info
```

I need to extract the name of the company, the email and site, also I need the bot to crawl the next pages: [https://www.acichapeco.com.br/associados/*busca*/?sc3=&c1&pg=2](https://www.acichapeco.com.br/associados/_busca_/?sc3=&c1&pg=2)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. So what did you try?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve